# How to configure VS2017 for Opencascade use?

Tags: c++, opencascade

Please forgive me if my English is not very good;In my step,I follow the video [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5zCHArA06E](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5zCHArA06E,but)

but I can't find any file in D:\Package\OpenCASCADE-7.7.0-vc14-64\opencascade-7.7.0\win64\vc14\bind,and can't find the folder"libd".

This photo is the way I download occ.So I want to know how to cinfigure Vs with Occ in the right way.I am unfamiliar with Cmaker, so I want to direct use VS with Occ.[This photo is the way I download occ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSN72.png)

Comment: Not many people will be willing to go through a video and match where you having problems. It is better to write the context of problem, such as what you are trying to achieve, and what you have done to get where you are.